# Get table cell content based on content of cell in neighbourhood

Tags: ruby, cucumber, page-object-gem

I have a table with the following structure:

```
<table class="table_class">
    <tr>
        <td>Label A</td>
        <td>Value A</td>
        <td>Label B</td>
        <td><div>Value B<a href="/some/href">Change</a></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Label C</td>
        <td><div><a href="/another/href">Value C</a></div></td>
        <td>Label D</td>
        <td><div><span><a href="/more/href"><span><img src="image/source.jpg"<img src="another/image.gif"></span></a><a href="even/more/href">Value D</a></span>&nbsp;<a href="/href">Change</a></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to get the the values ("Value A", "Value B", ...), but the only unique identifier for the table cells containing those values, are the table cells left to them ("Label A", "Label B", ...).

Any idea how to handle this properly within a PageObject?

Thanks in advance,
Christian

Comment: You can declare cells by index so something like `cell(:value_a,index: 1)`  and `cell(:value_b,index: 3)`  might work. Personally for parsing html I would use nokogiri as it has some really nice navigation methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an XPath with the `following-sibling` axis to find the values of adjacent cells.

For example, the following page object has a method that will find the label cell based on its text. From there, navigate to the next td element, which should be the associated value.

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  def value_of(label)
    # Find the table
    table = table_element(class: 'table_class')

    # Find the cell containing the desired label
    label_cell = cell_element(text: label)

    # Get the next cell, which will be the value
    value_cell = label_cell.cell_element(xpath: './following-sibling::td[1]')
    value_cell.text
  end
end

page = MyPage.new(browser)
p page.value_of('Label A')
#=> "Value A"
p page.value_of('Label B')
#=> "Value BChange"
```

Depending on your goals, you could also refactor this to use the accessor methods. This would allow you to have the methods for returning the value cell, its text, checking its existence, etc:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  cell(:value_a) { value_of('Label A') }
  cell(:value_b) { value_of('Label B') }

  def value_of(label)
    table = table_element(class: 'table_class')
    label_cell = cell_element(text: label)
    value_cell = label_cell.cell_element(xpath: './following-sibling::td[1]')
    value_cell
  end
end

page = MyPage.new(browser)
p page.value_a
#=> "Value A"
p page.value_a?
#=> true
```

Comment: Thanks, this working perfectly fine for cells with plain text (eg "Value A").
Any idea on how tow get "Value B", which is nested in a div within the cell? Thx!

Comment: This solution does work when the value is nested in a div. As seen in the first example, you get "Value BChange" since that is the text of the cell. Assuming the part you do not want is always a Change link, you could remove that part of the string when present. Is that what you are looking for?